# SELECT statement inside CASE clause in TSQL throws error

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, case

I had to fine tune a bunch of stored procedures and got one which had loads of `IF ELSE blocks` within them they had insert statements with transactions. Hence i modeled them using case to find that i get syntax errors try the below statement(a simple example of what is being done) but sure you will get the idea

```
DECLARE @rowcount int
SELECT @rowcount = -1
 CASE WHEN @rowcount = -1 THEN
    select 'I WON THE RACE'
 WHEN '2' 
    SELECT 'WHAT A LOSER'
 END
```

each cases have more than one statement, so i just encased them inside `(` and `)` but to noavail. Please correct my knowledge of Case in TSQL. **(Using SQl Server 2005 if that helps)**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want your `CASE` statement to look like this:

```
DECLARE @rowcount int
SELECT @rowcount = -1;
SELECT CASE @rowcount
          WHEN -1 THEN 'I WON THE RACE'
          WHEN 2 THEN 'I did not win'
       END AS columnName
```

The `CASE` goes inside of a `SELECT` statement.  Then you just look at the value of your `@rowCount`, and take the appropriate action.  You may want to read more about the [CASE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx) statement

The second form of a `CASE` statement looks like this:

```
SELECT CASE 
   WHEN @rowcount IS NULL THEN 'Null case here'
   WHEN @rowcount = -1 THEN 'I WON THE RACE'
   WHEN @rowcount = 2 THEN 'I did not win'
END AS columnName
```

If you want to use a CASE with an INSERT:

```
DECLARE @rowcount int
SELECT @rowcount = -1;

INSERT INTO myTable(column1, column2, column3)
SELECT CASE @rowcount
          WHEN -1 THEN 'I WON THE RACE'
          WHEN 2 THEN 'I did not win'
       END AS column1
   , t.column2
   , CASE
        WHEN t.someColumn < someValue THEN 'thirdColumnValue'
        ELSE 'someColumn is greater than specified value'
     END AS column3
FROM secondTable AS t
```

Comment: i am sorry if wasn't clear enough. That was just a example, **i got insert statements in place of those select** does it make no difference?

Comment: @Deeptechtons I have updated my answer to include an example of an `INSERT` using a `CASE` statement.

Answer (score 1):

From your comment, it sounds like you might want to use an IF statement if you're trying to do 2 different inserts/multiple statements?

```
IF @rowcount = -1
BEGIN
  <stmt1>
  <stmt2>
END

IF @rowcount = 2
BEGIN
  <stmt3>
  <stmt4>
END
```

Comment: Exactly, there are number of if else's in the stored procedure and i wanted to replace them with Case then. That's why i headed here.**So there isn't any replacement ?**

Comment: No, there's no replacement if the goal is to run entire statements like that. CASE is used within a statement to branch logic, not to execute new statements

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing T-SQL's `SELECT...CASE` with VisualBasic's `SELECT CASE.`

T-SQL:

> The CASE expression is used to evaluate several conditions and return
>   a single value for each condition. For example, it allows an
>   alternative value to be displayed depending on the value of a column.

VB:

> `Select...Case` runs one of several groups of statements, depending on
>   the value of an expression.

It would be nice if there was an equivalent in T-SQL, but there isn't. [Here's what's available in T-SQL.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174290.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

a suggestion only
you can also use set `set @rowcount = -1;`

```
DECLARE @rowcount int
set @rowcount = -1;
 select  CASE @rowcount WHEN -1 THEN
     'I WON THE RACE'
 WHEN '2' then
    'WHAT A LOSER'
 END Status
```

Comment: has nothing to do with my question